# How to create stacked bar chart with a time series and aggregated values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stackedbarseries

I am having difficulty creating a stacked bar chart time series from my Pandas dataframe (image below). I would like to have the 'Date' on the x axis, the 'Hours' on the y axis, and each bar to show the time spent with each group in 'Category'.

[image: Sample dataframe data]

Do I need to use Pandas - Groupby function? The dataframe is a sample. I have hundreds of rows of data from 2018 to 2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091904/7758804) to [pandas - stacked bar chart with timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45091855/7758804)

  - The issue with that question, is that OP is not aggregating any data, so that solution doesn't work for this question.
- Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` on `'date'` and `'group'`, while aggregating `.sum` on `'time'`

  - The `.dt` extractor is used to extract only the `.date` component of the `'date'` column.
  - Make certain the `'Date'` column of your dataframe is properly formatted as a `datetime` `dtype`, with `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`
- The grouped dataframe, `dfg`, must be shaped into the correct form, which can be accomplished with `pandas.DataFrame.pivot`.
- The easiest way to stack a bar plot is with `pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar` and use the `stacked` parameter.

  - See `pandas.DataFrame.plot` for all the parameters.

### Imports and Data Transformation

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random  # for test data
import numpy as np  # for test data

# setup dataframe with test data
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
rows = 1100
data = {'hours': np.random.randint(10, size=(rows)),
        'group': [random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C']) for _ in range(rows)],
        'date': pd.bdate_range('2020-11-24', freq='h', periods=rows).tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df.head())
   hours group                date
0      2     C 2020-11-24 00:00:00
1      4     B 2020-11-24 01:00:00
2      1     C 2020-11-24 02:00:00
3      5     A 2020-11-24 03:00:00
4      2     B 2020-11-24 04:00:00

# use groupby on df
dfg = df.groupby([df.date.dt.date, 'group'])['hours'].sum().reset_index()

# pivot the dataframe into the correct format
dfp = dfg.pivot(index='date', columns='group', values='hours')

# display(dfp.head())
group        A   B   C
date                  
2020-11-24  49  25  29
2020-11-25  62  18  57
2020-11-26  42  77   4
2020-11-27  34  43  17
2020-11-28  28  53  23
```

- More succinctly, the groupby and pivot step can be replaced with [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), which both reshapes and aggregates

  - `index=df.date.dt.date` is used so the index doesn't include the time component, since the data for the entire day is being aggregated.

```py
dfp = df.pivot_table(index=df.date.dt.date, columns='group', values='hours', aggfunc='sum')
```

### Plot

```py
# plot the pivoted dataframe
dfp.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6), ylabel='Hours', xlabel='Date', title='Sum of Daily Category Hours')
plt.legend(title='Category', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- There will be a bar for each day, this is how bar plot ticks work, so the plot could be very wide, if there are many dates.
- Consider using `pandas.DataFrame.barh`

```py
dfp.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(6, 10), title='Sum of Daily Category Hours')
plt.legend(title='Category', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.ylabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- The OP states there is data from 2018 to 2020, which means there could be over 700 days worth of data, which translates to over 700 bars in the bar plot.
- A standard line plot might be the best option to properly visualize the data.

```py
dfp.plot(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much, Trenton. This is the best explanation I have seen on the subject. You correctly identified that the graph would be messy with 700 days worth of data -- how would I aggregate the data to the month level if I still wanted a stacked bar chart instead of a line chart? I can aggregate by month but I lose the Category when I do so: df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B, %Y'),sort=False)['Hours'].sum()

Comment: @jecklymeister I'm glad this works for you. I don't have python open to test it, but you could try `df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.month, 'Group']).Hours.sum()` or `df.groupby([df.Date.dt.strftime('%B, %Y'), 'Group'], sort=False).Hours.sum()`, however, then the `x-axis` will not be a date. Another option is to create a new column, where the day in the `'Date'` is set to the 1st of the month. That way, when you groupby `df.date.dt.date` the `x-axis` will still be a datetime format. [Set the day to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889046/7758804).

Comment: Thank you again. I applied the second option (although I used strftime('%Y, %B' in order to get the dates in the right order) , reset the index, turned it into a pivot table, and then graphed per your first response. I got exactly what I need out of that! THANK YOU!